# Java: if and else returning true or false at every condition

Tags: java

Code:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (!(obj instanceof AbstractAnimal))
        return false;
    AbstractAnimal other = (AbstractAnimal) obj;
    if (name == null) {
        if (other.name != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
        return false;
    if (sound == null) {
        if (other.sound != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!sound.equals(other.sound))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

How can this expression be valid if it will always return true in the end? I don't get it, for example, if obj==NULL, it will return false, followed by true at the end of the function

Comment: Please post the code in the question, not a link.

Comment: You are welcome to use other sites like http://runnable.com/ to show your code running, however I would also advise clearly posting your code in stack and working to better define your question, problem, and what solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` immediately returns from the method, execution is not continued to the next statements. As a result you return only once from the method, you can ignore subsequent instructions

Comment: Wasn't aware of such a basic concept, much appreciated.
I'll accept the answer as soon as possible.